# Easiest way to share class across all processes in multiprocessing

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I have a class that starts multiple threads upon initialization. Originally I was using threading, but I learned the hard way how painfully slow it can get. As I researched this, it seems that multiprocessing would be faster because it actually utilizes multiple cores. The only hard part is the fact that it doesn't automatically share values. How could I make the following code share `self` across all processes?

Ideally, it would also share across processes outside of the class as well.
Also, I would rather share the entire class than share each individual value, if possible.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

class ThreadedClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
        #Here is where I would want to tell multiprocessing to share 'self'
        change_var = mp.Process(target=self.change_var, args=())
        print_var = mp.Process(target=self.print_var, args=())
        change_var.start()
        sleep(0.5)
        print_var.start()

    def change_var(self):
        while True:
            self.var += 1
            print("Changed var to ", self.var)
            sleep(1)

    def print_var(self):
        while True:
            print("Printing var: ", self.var)
            sleep(1)

ThreadedClass()
```

I also included output of the above code below:

```
Changed var to  1  
Printing var:  0  
Changed var to  2  
Printing var:  0 
Changed var to  3  
Printing var:  0  
Changed var to  4  
Printing var:  0 
Changed var to  5  
Printing var:  0  
Changed var to  6  
Printing var:  0 
Changed var to  7  
Printing var:  0  
Changed var to  8  
Printing var:  0 
Changed var to  9  
Printing var:  0  
Changed var to  10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you have to write to and from a Queue(). Workers can't really talk to each other without going through the manager.

Comment: @BobbyOcean How do I use a queue()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, multiprocessing means that you are making sub-processes. This means that in general, they have their own space in memory and don't talk to each other. To be clear, when you start a new multiprocessing thread, python copies all your global variables into that thread and then runs that thread separate from everything else. So, when you spawned your two processes, change_var and print_var, each of them received a copy of self, and since their are two copies of self, neither of them is talking to each. One thread is updating it's own copy of self and producing answers that are counting, the other is not updating self. You can easily test this yourself:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
LIST = [] # This list is in parent process. 
def update(item):
    LIST.append(item)
p = mp.Process(target=update, args=(5,)) # Copies LIST, update, and anything else that is global. 
p.start()
p.join()
# The LIST in the sub-process is cleaned up in memory when the process ends. 
print(LIST) # The LIST in the parent process is not updated.
```

It would be very dangerous if different processes were updating each other's variables while they were trying to process with them; hence, naturally to isolate them (and prevent "segmentation faults"), the entire namespace is copied. If you want sub-processes to talk to each other, you need to communicate with a manager and Queue that is designed for that.

I personally recommend to write your code around things like a Pool() instead. Very clean, input an array, get back an array, done. But if you want to go down the rabbit hole, here is what I read on the multiprocessing website.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(queue):
    queue.put(['stuff',15])
def g(queue):
    queue.put(['other thing'])

queue = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=f,args=(queue,))
q = mp.Process(target=g,args=(queue,))
p.start()
q.start()
for _ in range(2):
    print(queue.get())
p.join()
q.join()
```

The main idea is that the queue does not get copied and instead allows things to be left in the queue. When the you run queue.get() it waits for something in the queue to be gotten that was left by some other process. queue.get() blocks and waits. This means you could have one process read the contents of the other process, like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(queue):
    obj = queue.get() # Blocks this sub-process until something shows up. 
    if obj:
        print('Something was in the queue from some other process.')
        print(obj)
def g(queue):
    queue.put(['leaving information here in queue'])

queue = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=f,args=(queue,)) 
q = mp.Process(target=g,args=(queue,))
p.start()
```

This is kindof cool, so I recommend waiting here a second to think about what is waiting to process. Next start the q process.

```
q.start()
```

Notice that p didn't get to finish processing until q was started. This is because the Queue blocked and waited for something to show up.

```
# clean up 
p.join()
q.join()
```

You can read more at: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Queue